# How to make read only row in spreadsheet using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I have form response sheet, and I wanted to make some row to be in `read only` mode. How can I achieve it using Google Apps Script or any alternate methods are available for same.

Thank you!

Comment: Follow this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection), will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 2):

Two ways to solve this:

**Apps Script**

You want to use the *Protection* class of the Spreadsheet ([documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection)). This allows access to the built-in cell protection mechanisms.
Here's the example form the documentation for making a range read-only:

```
 // Protect range A1:B10, then remove all other users from the list of editors.
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var range = ss.getRange('A1:B10');
 var protection = range.protect().setDescription('Sample protected range');

 // Ensure the current user is an editor before removing others. 
 //  Otherwise, if the user's edit permission comes from a group, 
 //  the script will throw an exception upon removing the group.
 protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
 if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
   protection.setDomainEdit(false);
 }
 // Now the range is not editable by anyone. 
 //  Just add yourself back to the editors list if necessary.
 protection.addEditor(Session.getEffectiveUser());
```

**In the Sheets App**

You can access the cell & range protection mechanisms from within the Sheets app via the `Data` menu. Select `Data`>`Protect sheets and ranges...`, then set the permissions in side-bar.